# Search not selectable on iPhone

Tags: theming

I just finished a mobile-responsive site using an Omega sub-theme in Drupal 7. I just noticed that it is not possible to tap or double tap on an iPhone to access the search field.

I'm not sure where to begin looking for answers to this issue. Any suggestions?

Site:

http://dianalogan.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have found out what was going on. Omega builds the mobile page by changing the side-by-side layout of regions to a stacked layout. The region with the search field and button was layered behind another region in the same zone. Once I removed this layering, there was no issue. An easy fix.